# AWS Dead Letter Queue to Slack Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, slack, amazon-sns

I have a SQS with redelivery policy set for DLQ after 4 re-tries. But, I want to send the DLQ messages to Slack so the corresponding channel would receive direct messages which failed at lambda.

From the AWS documentation, my understanding is that there is no direct integration from SQS to Slack, so I would have to create an SNS, which will have trigger as DLQ, and a lambda triggered by SNS which will actually forward the message to specific Slack Channel.

```
SQS -> (4 * error-processing) -> DLQ -> SNS -> Lambda -> Slack.
```

So, first Question: Is there any simpler pattern for this integration? and Second, is there an option to automatically (AWS provided) add errorDetails as message attributes for message sent from SQS to DLQ.

Comment: I can tell you off the bat that SNS can be dropped from the chain, just SQS into lambda

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha: Yes, SNS can be taken out, as Lambda can directly trigger from DLQ. It came in picture as I was trying a direct `https` integration from SNS to Slack.